# Debian 11 VirtualBox drag and drop не работает

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox

В линуксах полный 0, только недавно второй раз установил linux дистрибьютив. Подскажите пожалуйста как активировать возможность drag'n'drop?? Галочки все нужные в VBOX стоят, VBoxLinuxAdditions в дебиан установил и размер экрана меняется, а вот перетаскивание файлов не работает. Есть предположение что это и за внутренних особенностей debian 11 и ее сборки, но даже не знаю куда копать. Сборка с оф сайта, обычная, все установлено со стандартными настройками который предлогались по мере установки. Гуглить уже задолбался.

Такой момент есть еще что до этого стояла ubuntu и там VBoxLinuxAdditions установился без проблем прям из файлового менеджера, а здесь пришлось заходить через рут и в терминале устанавливать так как в менеджере возникает "непонятная ошибка", может быть это и как-то связано с тем что невозможно активировать перетаскивание?? Или же думаю на оболочку рабочего стола. В убунту ярлыки хоть на рабочем столе были и было все windows-подобно и вроде внутри системы можно было перемещать файлы, а здесь даже на рабочий стол внутри системы папку нельзя переместить.

Answer (score 2):

если стоит Extension Pack и в устройствах активен Drag and Drop и двухнаправленный буфер обмена, то может быть проблема в видеодрайвере, можно юзать общие папки например, еще может быть кириллица в имени файла

Comment: не знаю extention или нет, но функции такие есть и они активированы, но не работают. конечно общие папки не сильно сложнее, но после часа гугла эта неполадка уже вызывает просто любопытство